# Are there any compound words (verb+noun) with the noun in singular?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, plurales, compuestos

In Spanish there are a lot of compound words:

- [Paraguas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RqaLq7W) ("parar" + "aguas").
- [Quitamanchas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ux77yGR) ("quitar" + "manchas").
- [Paracaídas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RpH4CZi) ("parar" + "caídas").

The common thing among them is that the noun part is always in plural form. So I wonder, are there any compound words in Spanish (in the form "verb+noun") with the noun expressed in singular?

Comment: Note that I'm not asking for a complete list, just if there are any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are.
A couple examples come to mind:

- [***quemarropa***](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=quemarropa), from *quemar* + *ropa*: close range, like in shots fired so close to someone that they leave burn marks in their clothes.
- [***cubrecama***](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=cubrecama), from *cubrir* + *cama*: bed cover.